# Different node symbols for d3.js force-directed graph

Tags: svg, graph, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

How do I display nodes as different symbols in d3.js's force-directed library?  I wanted to implement something similar to what I wrote below:

```
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node") 
      .data(graph.nodes) 
    .enter().append(function(d){return d.shape;}) 
      .attr("class", "node") 
      .attr("r", 5) 
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); }) 
      .call(force.drag);
```

Each node would have an encoded shape ("rect", "circle", etc.).  However, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (d){return "circle";} has no method 'indexOf'
```

The other question I have related to that is this: how would I toggle between applying different attributes for each shape?  Circles need an "r" attribute refined, but rects require "height" and "width".  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [d3.svg.symbol](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol), as in the [force-directed symbols](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062383) example.