# d3.js Force Chart online now app with different symbol shapes

Tags: charts, d3.js

I've built a force chart application.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/130/

I want to be able to define different shapes and maybe even change the fill backgrounds for specific user images. I'm aware of the def pattern method - is this best way to go about it. How do I create the function to control the shape of the node?

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g")
                        .attr("class", "circle")
                        .selectAll("circle")
                            .data(force.nodes())
                            .enter()
                            .append("svg:circle")
                        .attr("class", function(d) {
                            return "level"+d.level;
                        })                  
                        .attr("r", function(d) {
                            if(d.level > 0){
                                return getRadius(d);
                            }
                            else{
                                return "0";
                            }
                        })
                        .style("fill", function(d) {
                            return color(d.group);
                        })
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092228/add-different-shapes-to-d3-force-layout) and [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/Phrogz/2117368) should help.

Comment: In reference to this example, could it be possible to update the items as if they represented users coming on and offline?

Comment: Is it also possible to create custom shapes - like hearts, spades, clubs

Comment: You can make almost anything you like with a [superformula](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1020902).

Comment: Thank you Lars, also found this reference - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is the latest example - I've pushed the transform attributes on the exit to have the shapes fly to the left and up - keen to enhance/clean up the code - any help from anyone to make it more efficient?

**LATEST CODE -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/617/ **

```
 var users = that.vis.selectAll("path")
              .data(that.nodes);

        // Enter
        users
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("id", function(d){
                return d.id;
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
                  .size(function(d) { return d.size; })
                  .type(function(d) { return d.type; }))
            .style("fill", "steelblue")
            .style("stroke", "white")
            .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
            .call(that.force.drag);

        // Update
        users
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .transition()
        .duration(500);        

        // Exit
        users.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(-100,100)"; })
        .remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the example to start to mimic an "online now" application. I want to represent users via the symbols and have the symbols gravitate towards the center - much like the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/231/

I've toggled the data and managed to update the force chart - but its snapping instead of fading in and out the symbols and there is no gravitation - on start up or on update.

this is the current plot code

```
    //__morph plots
    var plots = this.vis.selectAll("path")
        .data(this.nodes)

    // Enter
    plots.enter()
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
              .size(function(d) { return d.size; })
              .type(function(d) { return d.type; }))
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
        .call(this.force.drag);


    // Update
    plots
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })     


    // Exit
    plots.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(250)
            .remove();
    //__morph plots
```

Comment: I've tried to toggle between 2 login data sets - I am trying to ensure there are no duplicates in the array - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/601/ - at the moment each second it reads a data stream and adds objects regardless if they exist or not.

Comment: I've added an isInArray check - so only unique id's are added to the array. I've tried to also add enter/update/exit to the user shapes themselves and to toggle the array to less users - but its not working as expected - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/609/

Comment: I've developed a pop element function to remove user's no longer online - but instead of the shapes distancing off from the center - they just pop out of existence - does anyone here have a solution - here is the latest fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/615/